# Did Sean Parker tell Mark Zuckerberg to drop the "The"?

Tags: historical-accuracy, the-social-network

As depicted at about the 1 hour 11 minute mark of *The Social Network (2010)*, Sean Parker — co-founder of Napster, and an early investor in and later the first President of Facebook — tells Mark Zuckerberg, the founder of what was then known as "The Facebook":

> **Sean Parker:** Drop the "the." Just "Facebook". It's cleaner.
>
> **Mark Zuckerberg:** [*shakes head in awe*] ...Shit.

The renaming was obviously an event that happened at some point in the company's early history, but was Sean Parker responsible for it, and how accurate is the movie exchange above to how it actually took place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes**, according to Ben Mezrich, author of *The Accidental Billionaires: The Founding of Facebook, a Tale of Sex, Money, Genius, and Betrayal* (the book *The Social Network* is based on).

> […] Thiel had given them the great news: **thefacebook was on its way.
> Or, as the company was now going to be called—just “Facebook.” Sean’s idea, because he’d been so damn annoyed by that *the* in the Web site’s name, he’d finally gone and gotten Mark to slice it right off** in the reorganization that was now an inevitability, a necessary step in getting that five-hundred-thousand-dollar “angel” investment that was going to save all their necks.

<sup>- *The Accidental Billionaires*, Chapter 25 - San Francisco (emphasis mine)</sup>

> Ben Mezrich maintains that the book is not a work of fiction despite his narrative style of writing. Some of his sources are his conversations with Facebook co-founder Eduardo Saverin and the court documents made available to him because of "all these college kids suing each other."

<sup>- [*The Accidental Billionaires* Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Accidental_Billionaires)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for looking up the source. Based on that excerpt and assuming it's the only place in the book where the name change is reference, I'm guessing that the idea was Sean's but the conversation itself was artistic license.

Answer (score 1):

Citing from the [mentioned article](https://cio.economictimes.indiatimes.com/news/corporate-news/how-sean-parker-bounced-back-from-being-fired-to-change-facebooks-history/46185974) dating back to 2015 it seems to be accurate.

> Before he convinced Mark Zuckerberg to drop the "the" and signed on as Facebook's first president, Sean Parker helped launch two other big startups: Napster and Plaxo

Comment: If the movie was made in 2010 and this article dates back to 2015, then how do we know the article wasn't using the movie as its source?